# Get all occurrences of data from text file using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a text file which contains lots of repetitive data.

```
COB TRAC
Green With Comments
Issue Description: Users were not able to use the document upload/download functionality as well as the ARP/TRP module of CoBTrac.
Root cause: GPA working with CATE to help troubleshoot the issue as we migrated from WebBank to Cloud this past Friday (10/20/15).  All other Modules are working fine.
Business Impact:  Users not able to upload document for CoBTrac.
Compensating Controls:  TBD.
Work around:  No workaround, GPA/CATE working on resolution.
Issue Reported On: 17th November 2015 – 12:17PM EST
Environment (Prod/UAT): PROD
Technology: Application
Engineer SOEID (Who has worked on this): RK55542
Ticket Type (VT/EMS) & Number & Status: HYPERLINK "https://servicemanagement.citigroup.net/nav_to.do?uri=incident.do%3Fsys_id=6e42f9df6ff34e00dad82fe64f3ee430%26sysparm_record_list=active=true%5esys_class_name!=u_major_incident"INC0026404246
Issue Category (APP/SA/DB): APP
Issue Severity: Medium

CitiRisk Credit
Green With Comments
Issue  Description:  The CitiRisk Credit Application Production Oracle RAC database server had one node (of three) go down due to a power issue.
Root Cause: Infrastructure issue - Server Power failure, RC to be determined. 
Application Impact :  As a result of this issues, 3 listeners and 1 data load job for the application failed. They were immediately re-run to success.
Business Impact:  None
Compensating Control: None
Work Around: DBA team is checking with service providers (Oracle & HP) to find a fix to such infra issue. The application team are looking at the reason for the failures of the listeners and data load job. 
Issue Reported On (Date/Time):    11:30 PM EST 11/24/2015
Environment (PROD/UAT):   PROD
Technology:   Oracle
Engineer SOEID (Who is working on this):  gg13851
Ticket Type(VT/EMS) & Number & Status:  INC0026451991 (SA) & INC0026451020 (DBA)
Issue Category(APP/SA/DB):    APP
Issue Severity:   Severity - 2 (High)
```

I need to get the data like Issue Severity, Issue Category, etc.

I am able to open the file and read but I dont know how to get all the required data for all tickets.

I am using following code to open the file

```
    Dim strTestFile2 As String
    strTestFile2 = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\ETSDaily.txt"
    Dim dataArray2 As Variant
    ' Open the file and assign data to array
    Open strTestFile2 For Input As #1
        dataArray2 = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbLf)
    Close #1
```

Comment: Typical case for regex.

Comment: Hi Jelly,

Thanks for the suggestion. I am quite new to VBA so could you please elaborate on this or provide a small example.

Thanks again

Comment: A regex is a library that is used to return substrings from strings matching a specific pattern. Before I can help you, can you please illustrate the input and desired output of your problem. What do you want to extract from that text.